# how to change YUI3 tab using javascript

Tags: yui3, tabview

I want to provide an additional link to change tab using YUI3.
I have a form spread over multiple tabs, so at the bottom of tab-contents I want a 'continue' link which will take use to next tab.

any ideas.

Answer (score 10):

myTabView.selectChild(index) is the correct way to change tabs programmatically.

Comment: I had quite a long time to search while found it. It worked like a charm. :)