# How to deep link YUI 3 Tabview?

Tags: yui3, deep-linking, tabview

Im using YUI3 and would like to deep link my tabs. I used tabview + history from YUI. how do i change the value for the url parameter

/#tab-2 
replace to 
/#tab-description

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674572/how-to-change-yui3-tab-using-javascript  Help is on the way in YUI3.4 -- http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2529954

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/HistoryHash.html

It has a setHash method which can do that work for you. Under the hood, it just changes what you have above. Ideally, you'll have some sort of infrastructure in history to listen for the hash change events (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/HistoryBase.html, history:change) to detect the change and perform you application code)